# Recursive Sudoku solver almost working but getting stack overflow for empty grid

Tags: c++, recursion, sudoku

I'm trying to solve Sudoku by recursive. The program working great. The problem is that the stack is only keep-able of 4-6K recursive. That's mean that if I'm leaving the soduku with more than 6-7 empty cells, the combination needed to solve it is:

```
    4^7 = 16384 > 4-5K...
```

How can I improve my program to work with less calls? The program is working good out of this problem. The function:

```
    void solve_soduku(int soduku[][N*N], int &row, int &col, const bool fix_v[][N*N])
```

is all the business.

I give you here all the numbers you need for correct soduku to not wast your time. You can some of them out and see how it's work:

```
    0 0 1
    0 1 2
    0 2 3
    0 3 4
    1 0 4
    1 1 3
    1 2 2
    1 3 1
    2 0 3
    2 1 1
    2 2 4
    2 3 2
    3 0 2
    3 1 4
    3 2 1
    3 3 3
    -1
```

and the code:

```
#include <iostream>     

using namespace std;

const int N = 2;

void zero_soduku(int soduku[][N*N]);
void zero_arr(int temp_arr[], int size);
void get_input(int soduku[][N*N], bool fixed_values[][N*N]);

void solve_soduku(int soduku[][N*N], int &row, int &col, const bool fix_v[][N*N]);

bool check_soduku(const int soduku[][N*N]);
bool check_rows(const int soduku[][N*N]);
bool check_cols(const int soduku[][N*N]);
bool check_sub_interval(const int soduku[][N*N]);

void print_soduku(const int soduku[][N*N]);

int main() {
    int soduku[N*N][N*N] = { 0 }, row = 0, col = 0;
    bool fixed_values[N*N][N*N] = { false };

    get_input(soduku, fixed_values);

    solve_soduku(soduku, row, col, fixed_values);

    cout << endl;

    print_soduku(soduku);

    system("pause");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

bool check_soduku(const int soduku[][N*N]) {
    if (check_rows(soduku) && check_cols(soduku) && check_sub_interval(soduku))
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool check_rows(const int soduku[][N*N]) {
    int temp_arr[N*N] = { 0 };

    for (auto i = 0; i < N*N; i++) {
        zero_arr(temp_arr, N*N);
        for (auto j = 0; j < N*N; j++)
            temp_arr[soduku[i][j] - 1]++;
        for (auto k = 0; k < N*N; k++)
            if (temp_arr[k]>1)
                return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool check_cols(const int soduku[][N*N]) {
    int temp_arr[N*N] = { 0 };

    for (auto i = 0; i < N*N; i++) {
        zero_arr(temp_arr, N*N);
        for (auto j = 0; j < N*N; j++)
            temp_arr[soduku[j][i] - 1]++;
        for (auto k = 0; k < N*N; k++)
            if (temp_arr[k]>1)
                return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool check_sub_interval(const int soduku[][N*N]) {
    int temp_arr[N*N] = { 0 };

    for (auto rows_intervals = 0; rows_intervals < N; rows_intervals++)
        for (auto cols_intervals = 0; cols_intervals < N; cols_intervals++)
            for (auto i = rows_intervals*N; i < rows_intervals*N + N; i++)
                for (auto j = cols_intervals*N; j < cols_intervals*N + N; j++) {
                    temp_arr[soduku[i][j] - 1]++;
                    //end of interval, check if !good interval
                    if (i == rows_intervals*N + N - 1 && j == cols_intervals*N + N - 1)  {
                        for (auto k = 0; k < N*N; k++)
                            if (temp_arr[k]>1)
                                return false;
                        zero_arr(temp_arr, N*N);
                    }
                }
    return true;
}

void solve_soduku(int soduku[][N*N], int &row, int &col, const bool fix_v[][N*N]) {
    static int counter = 0;
    counter++;
    cout << endl << counter << endl;

    //Not empty cell
    if (soduku[row][col] != 0)
        //Not end of line
        if (col < N*N - 1) {
            col++;
            solve_soduku(soduku, row, col, fix_v);
        }
        else
            //Not end of rows
            if (row < N*N - 1) {
                row++;
                col = 0;
                solve_soduku(soduku, row, col, fix_v);
            }
            else
                //end of soduku
                if (check_soduku(soduku)) {
                    print_soduku(soduku);
                    return;
                }
    ///////  Finishd soduku but answaer not good  //////////////////
                else
                    //Last cell not max
                    if (soduku[row][col] < N*N - 1) {
                        soduku[row][col]++;
                        print_soduku(soduku);
                        cout << endl;
                        solve_soduku(soduku, row, col, fix_v);
                    }
    //Last cell max, going back...
                    else {
                        while (soduku[row][col] == N*N || fix_v[row][col]) {
                            if (!fix_v[row][col]) {
                                soduku[row][col] = 1;
                                print_soduku(soduku);
                                cout << endl;
                            }
                            if (col > 0) {
                                col--;
                                continue;
                            }
                            if (col == 0 && row > 0) {
                                col = N*N - 1;
                                row--;
                            }

                        }
                        if (!fix_v[row][col]) {
                            soduku[row][col]++;
                            print_soduku(soduku);
                            cout << endl;
                        }
                        solve_soduku(soduku, row, col, fix_v);
                    }
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
                    //Empty cell
    else {
        soduku[row][col]++;
        print_soduku(soduku);
        cout << endl;
        solve_soduku(soduku, row, col, fix_v);
    }

}

void zero_arr(int temp_arr[], int size) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < size; i++)
        temp_arr[i] = 0;
}

void zero_soduku(int soduku[][N*N]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N*N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N*N; j++)
            soduku[i][j] = 0;
}

void get_input(int soduku[][N*N], bool fixed_values[][N*N]) {
    cout << endl << "Please enter locatin and nums into soduku: ";
    int row = 0, col, value;
    while (row != -1) {
        cin >> row;
        if (row == -1)
            return;
        cin >> col >> value;
        soduku[row][col] = value;
        fixed_values[row][col] = true;
    }
}

void print_soduku(const int soduku[][N*N]) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < N*N; i++)
        for (auto j = 0; j < N*N; j++) {
            cout << soduku[i][j] << " ";
            if (j == N*N - 1)
                cout << endl;
        }
    //system("pause");
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: I think this belong to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You probably need to switch from recursive to another method to solve it then.

Comment: @mantal when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm appears to be, roughly:

1) Try each move in turn

2) Check the entire board to see if it's valid

3) Repeat until the entire board is filled

This is obviously very inefficient. The code will be making many moves which are illegal, then only realizing this belatedly, after fact.

I would suggest that you completely get rid of this, and attempt to implement something a little bit more efficient. Try to think how carbon-based life forms solve sudoku puzzles, and implement the same algorithm. Do you also do the above approach, when you solve a sudoku puzzle? Of course not. You do something like this:

1) For each position on the board, instead of storing just the current number in that position, if any, also store additional information: namely, if there is no number in that position, also store all possible numbers which would legal moves for that position.

For a completely empty board, for example, each position on the sudoku board would contain all values 1-9. From this, we then make the next logical step:

2) When making a move and placing a value in some position, say 4, you will remove the value 4 from all other cells in its 3x3 square, and remove 4 from all other cells in the same row and column. Because that number will no longer be a valid move in those cells. Conversely, when undoing a move, and removing the 4 from the cell, this means that the value 4 is now legal in all cells in its 3x3 square, and its row and column, so you would put this value in all of those positions, as a number that's now a legal move in those positions.

3) When deciding which next move to make, scan the board first, looking for any cell that has only one possible legal number. This means, of course, that this is the only legal move for that cell, so you make it.

4) If you find any cell that has no legal values left, this means that you reached an unsolvable state, so you'll undo your last move, and then try the next valid move from that point on.

5) Otherwise, you should just pick one of the cells that has the fewest possible legal moves left, make the first move, then keep going, then if you reach an unsolvable state, and return to this move, you undo it, and try the next move.

This seems to me an approach that should be much more efficient, as it should end up making the least number of illegal moves.

It is also closely mimics how carbon-based lifeforms solve sudoku puzzles by themselves.

P.S. To initialize a new sudoku puzzle with prefilled numbers, just start with an empty sudoku board, with all cells allowing all numbers 1-9 as legal moves, then make each move, as described above, to fill in the initial numbers on the sudoku board.